# xmgrace pipe nxy together

Tags: plot, xmgrace

Can the -nxy option be used together with the -pipe option?

For example, suppose "somecommand" produces an output with 5 columns (x y1 y2 y3 y4). I could plot the y's as a function of x using

```
somecommand > tmp.dat
xmgrace -nxy tmp.dat
```

Can I bypass the creation of the file tmp.dat using the -pipe option and still plot the 4 different y's together?

```
somecommand | xmgrace -pipe
```

would plot the y1 vs x. I would like to have all the y's vs x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just pass `-` to `-nxy` to tell xmgrace to use stdin as the data source:

```
somecommand | xmgrace -pipe -nxy -
```

Comment: How does one choose the columns? Is there a way to include more plot options? I wish to select x/y range while monitoring an evolving output of "somecommand" where piping the data works best. If there is, kindly suggest.

Comment: You can use a parameter file to set ranges. I don't think you can choose the columns, unless you don't use something like `somecommand | awk '{print $1, $3}' | xmgrace ...` to select (in this example) the first and third columns. Fill free to make your own question if you want a more thorough answer though.